# Scroll snapped to the page's bottom after new lazy loaded content comes

Tags: angular, scroll, loading, lazy-evaluation

In Angular 7 project I have a Page with a list of products. On it there's a "Load more products" button (kind of lazy loading). on it's click a request goes to server , when response comes it is added to current pruduct list. The problem is that I expected the page to "stay in place" after reponse comes so I can see the last browsed product and continue scrolling. To my surprise it works different it stays snapped to the bottom so I see footer and "Load more ... " button after the response comes.

I tried to scroll it to it's last position before new content was loaded but it doesn't work. I used elemnet.scroll(x,y) method because window.scrollTo(x,y) is broken in our App :) .a AHh junior's job :P.

*// Below - function witch loads new content in ProductListComponent*

*// this.scrollTop is a property calculated in other part of the component, I don't put it to not distract you.*

```
getProductListById(...someArgs).pipe(
        tap(payload => {
          let newItems = [];
          newItems = this.productList;
          newItems.push(...this.filterList(payload.items));
          this.productList = [...newItems];
        }),
        finalize(() => {
          this.screenService.scrollTo.next(this.scrollTop);
        })
      );
```

*// ScreenService
// it was created due to broken window.scrollTo() method. It works in all other cases but here...*

```
 public scrollTo: Subject<number> = new Subject();
```

*// CoreComponent*

```
ngOnInit(){    
this.screenService.scrollTo.pipe(takeUntil(this.unsubscribe)).subscribe(scrollTop => {
      this.scrollTo(scrollTop);
    });
}

  scrollTo(scrollTop: number) {
    if (!isNaN(scrollTop)) {
      this.scrollContainer.nativeElement.scroll(0, scrollTop);
    }
  }
```

I don't count on fixing scroll if there is another way to keep the page in it's place and disable this snapping behavior please tell me.
Hope for some advices.

Comment: Hey. actually the real problem was that i put product list container and some other container to the grid container and forgot they were set to "align-items: stretch". To bring back normal scrolling behavior I had to set it to "align-items: start". Ultimately solved.

Answer (score 0):

The problem here is that you are refilling the array of the product list that is why your page stays in the footer always I have also implemented same thing in my project but I add the items directly to the original list but not putting all the list items again into the list.

Here the browser maintains some kind of binding with the elements so adding all the items in the list makes it stay always at the bottom.

> Try to add directly into the original list

This way

```
getProductListById(...someArgs).pipe(
        tap(payload => {
this.productList.push(...this.filterList(payload.items))})
      );
```

Then you may not need the service to scroll also.

Comment: Hey. actually the real problem was that i put product list container and some other container to the grid container and forgot they were set to "align-items: stretch". To bring back normal scrolling behavior I had to set it to "align-items: start". Ultimately solved. I tested your solution together with this and that's why I was excited at the beggining :P